# Is there a way to delete line with a keyword using seek()? Why rewriting line using seek() skips my input lines?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and making a program with product() in it. I have an input .txt file with lines. It takes banlist, which can contain same line as in input .txt file.
I need to delete some lines that contain specific keyword. I have tried using seek() to write only lines that i need, but i keep getting unusual results that can be repeated lines, deleting not working.

```
from itertools import product
with open('banLeftSide.txt') as f:
    c = f.read().splitlines()
with open('banRightSide.txt') as f:
    d = f.read().splitlines()
with open('input.txt') as f:
    a = f.read().splitlines()
with open('input.txt') as f:
    b = f.read().splitlines()

if c != []:
    for i,thing in enumerate(a):
        if thing in c:
            a[i] = 'keyword'

if d != []:
    for i,thing in enumerate(b):
        if thing in d:
            b[i] = 'keyword'

temp = product(a, b)
for i in list(temp):
    li = list(i)
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in product(a, b):
            if i[0] != i[1]:
                f.write(" - ".join(i) + '\n')

with open('output.txt', 'r'+) as txt_file:
    temp = txt_file.readlines()
    txt_file.seek(0)

    for line in temp:
        if not 'keyword' in line:
            txt_file.write(line)
```

Examples of input.txt:
a
b
c
d
Examples of banLeftSide.txt or banRightSide.txt:
c

Comment: You read the entire file, seeked back to the beginning, and then wrote a lesser amount of data to it.  The original end of the file is still there, after the end of the written data.  You need to call `.truncate()` on the file to chop off that leftover data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Can you please tell me how can i truncate leftover?

Comment: Also can i truncate to chop off leftover data if data in input.txt changes?